# Oracle SQL query to get the max logins per hour from am_session table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to get the max logins per hour from am_session table which has columns : userid, create_time (datatype:timestamp(6)).

Attached the sample data.

[image: Sample data]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us the result you want for this sample data, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below -

```
select 
to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as create_date, 
extract(hour from create_time) as Hour,
Count(*)
from am_session
group by 
to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
extract(hour from create_time)
order by 1, 2 desc;
```

Note : This will not provide you count for hours where there was no login.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just aggregate:

```
select to_char(create_tme, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') as yyyymmddhh, COUNT(*)
from am_session
group by to_char(create_tme, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want the hour independently of the date, then:

```
select to_char(create_tme, 'HH24') as yyyymmddhh, COUNT(*)
from am_session
group by to_char(create_tme, 'HH24')
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Gordon Linoff.   Query shows below output                 2020-10-01 08  423.  Is there a way to get the count for each hour ?